# Hiding HTML template from client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, template-engine

I want to keep my client-side code as clean and minimal as possible. My project uses Knockout JS and this template engine: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates. I've created the template at the bottom of my source code with the computed values rendering in a "pre" section per the teamplate (that I don't really want visible). Is there a way to hide the template and call it when the DOM loads?

Comment: have you tried external templates that can be called only on demand?

Comment: I am using Node as well, I should add, and there is a solution server side. But, that will slow complicate my app by having to pass my knockout data to the server and then back.

Answer (score -1):

To load your templates from the server, put them in their own little `.html` files and then on the client, you can use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) to fetch them into a variable:

```
// The variable that we're going to put the template in
var myTemplate;

$.ajax({
      async: false,
      type: "GET",
      url: "/templates/myTemplate.html",
      success : function(data) {
            myTemplate = data;
      }
 });
```

Then when you want to use the template, you can call `templ()` with the template:

```
 var result = tmpl(myTemplate, data);
```

*Note:* I've forced jquery to be synchronous using `async:false` because you want to make sure the template is there when you call on it.

Comment: If there are a lot of templates to run, won't there be too much overhead?

Comment: Where is the overhead? You're downloading the html anyway, it makes little difference if you're doing over AJAX or putting it into the body when the request is first made.

Comment: I have this within my ko.computed function where the data is sent to the template. But it does not seem to be working. My GET request does show a 200 HTTP status code, though.

Comment: Does my template.html file need to just have the script tags wrapped around the template HTML or just the templated HTML? Do I need the rest of the HTML document even?

Comment: The template should only include just the HTML needed to build the snippet of output you need.

Comment: Ok. I will be losing this from the template: "<script type="text/x-tmpl" id="template-person">" Is this necessary to declare that it is of type template?

Comment: I don't think blue-imp needs that, it's more for hiding the template from the user when it first renders the page.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will continue to work on this. I am not generating the output yet from this method, but logically this seems to make sense. I may need to dig a little deeper within Knockout's docs to make sure I am not overlooking something.